# Networking unreachable with Ubuntu 16.10 Server and J3455B-ITX

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, dhcp

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu `16.10` (with kernel `4.8`) and the network isn't connecting (via Ethernet). The machine is a new J3455B-ITX mobo/CPU combo.

Here's what `ifconfig` shows:

```
enp1s0: ///
lo: ///
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Here's the output of `services networking status`:

```
Active: failed (Result: timeout)
Starting Raise networking interfaces...
waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.enp1s0
networking.service start operation timed out. terminating.
Failed to start Raise network interfaces
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server available for the enp1s0 interface? What means "netmask ...." in interfaces file as you want to use DHCP configuration?

Comment: Yes I already have a router on the network that is the DHCP server. The only reason I added the netmask was because I noticed in the logs it was searching for 255.255.255.255.

Comment: To be sure, if you have all required drivers (included firmware files) try to setup static IP (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html) and check if you will have access to the internet.

Comment: The issue there is I’ve never had network access (I installed this last night) so I don’t have a way to know or get what drivers I may need.

Comment: Did you try setup static IP for network interface?

Comment: Yep, now any pings result in “8.8.8.8 unreachable” or whatever address I pinged.

Comment: Any other device behind a router have access to the internet? Did you have an answer for ping to gateway - IP address of your router?

Comment: The rest of the devices on the network are fine. I cannot ping the router or any IP address from the box in question.

Comment: After fresh boot provide some details about your hardware:
1. ipconfig; 2. ipconfig -a; 3. lspci -vvk | grep Ethernet -A 11; 4. dmesg | grep eth

Comment: @mariaczi Sorry for the delay. Here's my output:
1. ipconfig doesn't exist
2. same
3. [output of lspci](https://gist.github.com/asimpson/43b6ad8a9013cd52cbb291c7e453cbe9)
4. [output of dmesg](https://gist.github.com/asimpson/44579f2c916b393ec10cc0052f461696)

Comment: sorry. ipconfig is on Windows systems. I think about ifconfig.

Comment: And once more - please show output from "ps -ef | grep dhcp" and the output from "ip a s" and "ip r s" when you have setup static IP. Maybe stupid, but important :) - LEDs on ethernet card blinking?

Comment: - [ifconfig output](https://gist.github.com/96c6a8fbdf63ed0ec1b7c614cb106c23)
- [ip a s output](https://gist.github.com/bbaad56518da9e71ca0aa44ac3579724)
- no output for `ip r s`
- [ps output](https://gist.github.com/3f5c1c3d35a0002830f0c470b318c6d2)

Setting static IP doesn't change anything :(

Comment: The output for "ip a s" is for the time when you have connected one of or both your ethernet inetrface to the switch? As you can see, you have "DOWN" state for both.

Comment: Trying to raise the interface fails and prints: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your computer is having two network cards, enp2s0 = RTL8168g/8111g, enp1s0 = Intel(R) PRO/1000

Are you completely sure that your ethernet cable is on Intel, not the realtek?

Seems that your cable is connected to enp2s0 not enp1s0. I made that conclusion of this line you show (see the no-carrier flag):

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:4b:68:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:39:ed:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I Suggest you try to replace your networking config to raise interface as enp2s0 with configuration like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Actually you don't need netmask, dhcp broadcast to 255.255.255.255 should go to every device on your layer2 network.

Comment: Ah you nailed it! Thank you so much! For my own edification what does 'no-carrier' mean? I'll award the bounty when it allows me to...

Comment: No carrier means there is no active line connected to your network card.